# Android Studio highlights all Java classes with JNI functions

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, android-studio-4.2

Since the update to Android Studio 4.1.0 stable, all of my classes with JNI implemented functions are colored as red with code highlight.

[image: Red example]

Below you can see my project structure. There are several library projects and the main `ck-learn` project. All the classes with the native code are placed in `jni-wrappers` project, while `CMakeLists.txt` is in a top library project `peshka` which uses `jni-wrappers` (see screenshot).

The syntax was colored as usual in Android Studio 4.0.2. All the classes were visible in the `peshka` project. But now they are highlighted with red, as they were not found. But the projects compiles as usual. It is only a visual problem.

If I open someof the files colored in red, there is a warning:

> This .java file is outside of Java source roots and won't be added to
> the classpath.

The source roots are standard (`src\main\java`) and it all was fine in AS 4.0.2.

Can someone help with this problem?

[image: Project structure]

Comment: Hi, did you manage to fix it? I'm having the same issue after upgrading to 4.1

Comment: Hi @Pat. No, the issue is still there. Some of my colleagues downgraded to AS 4.0.2.

Comment: Can you try 4.1.1? This smells like http://issuetracker.google.com/issues/171334504.

Comment: @protossor. Thanks a lot! 4.1.1 solves the issue. Finally I'm able to fully use my favorite Android Studio! Can you write an answer, so we'll close the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As confirmed by the OP from the comment, this is caused by a [bug](http://issuetracker.google.com/issues/171334504) in Android Studio 4.1.0, which gets partially fixed in Android Studio 4.1.1. The full fix is still in progress. More details on the symptoms and workaround can be found from this [bug](http://issuetracker.google.com/issues/171801044).

Answer (score 0):

Double check your `sourceSets` configuration. We had similar issue and it turned out to be caused main module pointing to sources inside the other module. Android Studio 4.0 accepted such config but Android Studio 4.1 doesn't.